# create a dev chainspec with specific test users

Tags: balances, chainspec, cli, polkadot-local, test-network

I'd like to use the Polkadot CLI to create a chainspec with specific user balances pre-seeded. I'd like to be able to do this for any of the dev runtimes.

In the case of the polkadot dev runtime, I run `polkadot build-spec --dev`. In the case of others, I run `polkadot build-spec --chain=<runtime-name-here>-local`. I capture the output in a file, and then overwrite its `genesis.runtime.balances.balances` with a list of `[ss58, amount]` tuples.

Then I write the updated chainspec to my fs, and run it with `polkadot --chain <path-to-spec>`. In the case of Westend, I'm able to retrieve a test user balance. All others fail. Also, westend txs stall.

Comment: Hi Harry, are you getting the `raw` version after you update the `genesis` file?

Comment: For future readers: we attempted to create a `raw` version from the edited, and still ran into the same issue. Will follow up if/when it's resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Achieved in Capi's devnet spawning logic [like so](https://github.com/paritytech/capi/blob/57f09bd0a2d0a9f54e1ce1eaef8b9f0549eede75/nets/chain_spec/addDevUsers.ts).